# IAMCameraControl Interface. How to tell when camera is done moving?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to write an app in C++ using IAMCameraControl. I have found Set, Get, etc. but I cannot find a way to actually tell if the camera has completed moving (ex, CameraControl_Pan).

My goal is to turn on autofocus, move the camera, then turn off autofocus after camera has stopped moving and ,if possible, stopped focussing.

Comment: What does *"has completed moving"* mean?

Comment: @IInspectable -  Ex. Pan from far right to far left may take 10 seconds. I want to know when it is finished moving to the far left.